# Vienna Convention on Road Traffic(1968) Letters Only Vehicle Registration Plate

Tags: international, driving, treaty

There is a large media scandal in Romania about a car that had a preferential number from another country. According to police, the number was illegal because was having letters only and no digits so basically, this number was violating [Vienna Convention on Road Traffic (1968)](https://treaties.un.org/pages/ViewDetailsIII.aspx?src=TREATY&mtdsg_no=XI-B-19&chapter=11&Temp=mtdsg3&clang=_en) (wikipedia link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Convention_on_Road_Traffic)) that was ratified by Romania in 1980.

Now according to a UN official that convention was modified in 2016 and because Romania did not oppose it is should be automatically applied. The amendment allows letters only plate. Is there any UN law/directive that says that a country that doesn't oppose an amendment is accepting it by default?

Comment: It would depend upon the exact language of the Vienna Convention on Road Traffic governing amendments and regulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [convention itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Convention_on_Road_Traffic) specifies that a country must explicitly declare its non acceptance of an amendment in order to be exempted from an amendment that is otherwise accepted.  So it seems that the UN official was correct.

Comment: thank you for your answer. could you let me know the article and chapter?

Comment: @user1121883 yes, but I may not be able to do it for a couple of days.